# Prove that the natural numbers are either the result of the subtraction of two elements in a particular set or exist as elements in the set

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, induction, pigeonhole-principle

Prove that in a set  made of  natural numbers  which every element  follows  ${a_n}$<2n  and  ${a_n}$<${a_{n+1}}$,
every natural number is either found in the set or the result of the subtraction of two elements of this set.
obviously the first element of the sequence will be one but the other elements have other possibilities for example the set could be 1,3,4,7,9,  or it could be 1,3,5,7,9,... how do we go on to prove this?

Comment: It seems that this problem is supposed to be proved by the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: It did actually cross my mind . But I don't know how to use pigeon hole principle here . I thought of   counting the numbers  that can be formed using the subtractions and how many already exist in the set but I don't know if it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by contradiction.

Let's suppose some number $n$ does not occur in the sequence. Then, the numbers $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are all distinct and lie in $\{1,\dots,n-1,n+1,\dots,2n-1\}$.

That set can be partitioned into $n-1$ pairs of numbers with distance $n$. By the pigeonhole principle, in one of the pairs both numbers must be one of the $a_1,\dots,a_n$.

Comment: I don't see the contradiction here. This is a direct proof.